# elasticsearch query LIKE multiple terms with OR

Tags: elasticsearch

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE field1 LIKE '%keysearch%' OR field2 LIKE '%keysearch%' OR field3 LIKE '%keysearch%';
```

How to translate this query to elasticsearch query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way to do this is using `query_string`:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index/tablename/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": { 
         "query":"*keysearch*", 
         "fields": ["field1","field2","field3"]
     }
   }
}'
```

query_string will use OR by default and will support a wildcard.

However your performance won't be great if using leading and trailing wildcards.

Comment: Thanks! It worked pretty well. The result is pretty standard. But I found it was not a reasonable arrangement. How to streamline and prioritize the order field1, field2, field3? please help me!

Comment: I guess this should be a separate question - but you need to research scoring and see how you can **boost** the score of one field over another. Simplest but less flexible is to do a boost at [index time](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html). More flexible is in the query (look at **boosting query** or **function score**).